# How can I drill a hole 8 ft deep through hard sandstone with a rotary hammer?

Tags: drill

At my property I would like to get a 1-2" hole 8 ft deep. The only problem is, I start hitting rock (hard sandstone) about a foot deep.

Is there some kind of shank extension for a rotary hammer that I can use to get down there? I have ground rods in a trench, and they're okay, but I really would like to see if I can get one to 8 ft.

Comment: [Sure](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS778US778&q=sds+bit+extension). Obviously you'd need several. Did you have a more specific question about it?

Comment: Did you use ground enhancement material in the trench?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/15757/46271. Check out the videos in this related q/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roto hammer is not designed to drill any where near that deep.  You can try to drive the ground rod with the roto hammer. They rent an attachment.  If it is indeed sand stone and not too hard it may drive it through.  Other wise be content with the trenched ground rods.  This method is widely and successfully used. You could contact a highway construction company and find out the going rate for a rock boring drill.